# Assembly Management in .NET, can we create our own "Assembly caches"?

Tags: .net, gac

Currently we have a group of projects deployed on a server running .NET.  Most of the projects reference Assemblies between them.  However since most developers for various reasons won't be given access to the GAC, we were wondering is there an easy way to create local "Assembly Caches" where groups of assemblies can be stored and used away from the Global Assembly Cache by projects with the know-how to access this cache?  We thought about uniting the projects under one big project and creating one big bin directory, but we were wondering if someone has tried something else.  Thanks!

Comment: Why use an assembly cache at all? Why not deploy DLLs alongside the applications that use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hook [assembly resolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) and implement custom behaviour to your hearts' content.

Comment: Yes you could - but don't let the load context bite you in your ass: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/06/13/switching-to-the-load-context.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx